Monte Carlo Control Reinforcement Learning
I'm reading the "Reinforcement Learning" book by Sutton & Barto. It's available here http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf . I'm currently in chapter 5 on Monte Carlo methods.
I have followed the argument why first-visit MC prediction yields an unbiased estimate of the value function associated with a particular policy, $V^{\pi}$. The authors then argue that this is not enough to improve the policy if we don't know the transition probabilities $P[s',r|s,a]$. That's all fair enough.
But the MC method they propose in section 5.2 seems like a very "data-hungry" idea involving all sorts of complications (exploring starts, strictly randomizing policies etc). They essentially forget about the estimated value function $\hat{V}^{\pi}$ and instead estimate the q-values from scratch generating random pairs of actions and states.
Sure, that'll work. But isn't the following idea much less "data-hungry": Take the policy $\pi$, use MC to estimate $V^{\pi}$ and obtain $\hat{V}^{\pi}$. Then for every state, try every action $N_{mc}$ times ($N_{mc}$ is the number of MC iterations) and look at what reward and new state $S'$ you get. Then approximate $q_{\pi}(s,a)$ by
$$q_{\pi}(s,a) = \frac{1}{N_{mc}}\sum_{i=1}^{N_{mc}} R_i+\gamma \hat{V}^{\pi}(S_i'),$$
where $R_i$ is the reward of the $i$-th Monte Carlo for the pair (s,a) and $S_i'$ is the new state after starting in $s$ and taking action $a$ in the $i$-th Monte Carlo.
It seems to me that this is an improvement over their policy because it avoids generating an entire sequence to estimate the action values (and thus seems to solve the problem of "maintaining exploration").
I'm sure there must be something I'm missing. Perhaps this is for pedagogical reasons to motivate algorithms in later chapters?
